# BackgroundWorker não recebe valor selecionado do ComboBox

Tags: c#, winforms

Tenho um ComboBox de objetos e estou criando um BackgroundWorker para adicionar esses objetos no meu banco de dados. Sem usar o BackgroundWorker eu consigo pegar o objeto selecionado mas quando uso o BackgroundWorker retorna uma excessão e o objeto está vazio.

Como resolver isso ?

Estou tentando assim.

**Metodo que o BackgroundWorker executa**

```
/** insere Perfil + Modulo */
        private void insertPerfilModulo() {            
            Perfil perfil = (Perfil)cbxPerfilModulo.SelectedItem;
            IList<Modulo> lista = getListaModulo();

            foreach(Modulo m in lista){                
                Permissao permissao = new Permissao();
                permissao.perfil = perfil;
                permissao.modulo = m;

                Boolean exist = dao.isExistPerfilAndModulo(permissao);                
                if (exist) {
                    Permissao p = dao.getPermissao(permissao);                    
                    dao.update(p);
                }else {
                    dao.insert(permissao);
                }
            }
        }
```

**DoWork**

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e) {
            progressBar1.Visible = true;
            insertPerfilModulo();
        }
```

**Botao que executa**

```
private void btnSalvarPM_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {            
            backgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
```

**Exception**

```
The thread '<No Name>' (0x1870) has exited with code 0 (0x0).
'PubControl.vshost.exe' (Managed (v4.0.30319)): Loaded 'C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.Numerics\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.Numerics.dll', Skipped loading symbols. Module is optimized and the debugger option 'Just My Code' is enabled.
A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.dll
The program '[5396] PubControl.vshost.exe: Program Trace' has exited with code 0 (0x0).
The program '[5396] PubControl.vshost.exe: Managed (v4.0.30319)' has exited with code -1 (0xffffffff).
```

Comment: Já tentou especificar os membros em que o `backgroundWolker1` vai acessar? Por exemplo, coloque `nomeDaClasse.progressBar1.Visible = true;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Muito provavelmente a exceção "System.InvalidOperationException" refere-se a "Cross-thread operation not valid".

Isso se dá pois só é possível fazer mudanças em um controle de um Form pelo thread no qual a janela do mesmo se encontra.

> Controls in Windows Forms are bound to a specific thread and are not
>   thread safe. Therefore, if you are calling a control's method from a
>   different thread, you must use one of the control's invoke methods to
>   marshal the call to the proper thread. This property can be used to
>   determine if you must call an invoke method, which can be useful if
>   you do not know what thread owns a control.

Fonte: [Control.InvokeRequired](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/system.windows.forms.control.invokerequired(v=vs.90).aspx)

Já que você está executando o código em um Background Worker (ou seja, outro thread), é gerada a exceção.

A solução é usar um invoke para chamar o método `insertPerfilModulo()` e mover `progressBar1.Visible = true;` para o mesmo.

```
private void backgroundWorker1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    Invoke((MethodInvoker) insertPerfilModulo());
}
```